# jQuery test for whether an object has a method?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to test whether a jQuery object has a particular method?  I've been looking, but so far without success.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `!!$obj.method`? Or is this more complicated than that?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc No need for `!!` in a conditional statement.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H My point was just check for truthiness. But it's hard to get that across with just `$obj.method`, so I added the bangs for clarification.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc No problem, there's [not much speed difference](http://jsperf.com/double-bang-in-if).

Comment: You have a nice answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5159690/1257607)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This should work:

```
if (!!$.prototype.functionName)
```

Answer (score 24):

Because jQuery methods are prototype into a jQuery object, you can test it from the prototype object.

```
if( $.isFunction( $.fn.someMethod ) ) {
    // it exists
}
```

This uses the [`jQuery.isFunction()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/) method to see if `$.fn.someMethod` is indeed a function. *(In jQuery `jQuery.fn` is a reference to the prototype object.)*

Comment: +1.  This is the only one that actually checks if it's a calalble function, and not just a member variable...

Comment: For others who are perhaps as slow on the uptake as I am: if you are, for example, checking to see if the UI Tabs method exists, use `$.isFunction($.fn.tabs)`. Hey, I needed a concrete example; maybe someone else does, too.

Comment: Deprecated in 3.3.0

Answer (score 5):

try

```
if ($.fn.method) {
    $('a').method(...);
}
```

or

```
if ($.method) {
    $.method(...);
}
```

Comment: -1, you're calling jQuery unneccessarily in the first example, that's more than 90% slower! http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-jquery-fn

Comment: `if ($.method) {` doesn't work for me. I had to use `if ($.fn.method) {`

Answer (score 0):

```
//Simple function that will tell if the function is defined or not
function is_function(func) {
    return typeof window[func] !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction(window[func]);
}

//usage

if (is_function("myFunction") {
        alert("myFunction defined");
    } else {
        alert("myFunction not defined");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to look for undefined

```
if( typeof jQuery("*").foo === "undefined" ){
  alert("I am not here!");
}
```

Comment: you could optimize a little by not getting every single element when they're not needed :)

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me

```
if (typeof myfunctionname === 'function')
```