# How to check if a function is already defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check if a function is already defined ?

Comment: I had problems checking type with the options shown bellow, it was returning string and not function as expected. I changed from `typeof var_with_func_name` to `typeof window[var_with_func_name]`, and it worked properly.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Javascript functions that check if a function exists.**

With [jQuery.isFunction()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/) you may test a parameter to check if it is (a) defined and (b) is of type "function." Since you asked for jQuery, this function will tickle your fancy.

```
jQuery.isFunction(YourFunction)
```

If you wish not to use jQuery for whatever reason, here's a barebones function based on code from [Idealog](http://www.idealog.us/2007/02/check_if_a_java.html) that will check if the variable is of type `function`.

```
function isFunction(fn){
    return typeof fn === 'function'
}
```

Sometimes you already know it's a function and for the sake of optimization find no reason to recheck it's type, in this case, here's function that simply checks if the `variable` [possibly a function] is defined

```
function isDefined(foo){
    return typeof(foo) !== 'undefined'
}
```

**How to use these functions**

Using jQuery:

```
function foo(){}
if(jQuery.isFunction(foo)) alert('This is a function');
```

With either of the *non-jQuery* Javascript functions provided above. Depending on the context of usage, these functions may, or may not be reliable. See more below

```
function foo(){}
if(isFunction(foo)) alert('is of type function');
if(isDefined(foo)) alert('if this is a function, it is defined');
```

Check both undefined and using `jQuery.isFunction`

```
if (typeof myfunc !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction(myfunc)) {
    //do something
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027715/jquery-isfunction-check-error-function-is-not-defined/20027726#20027726)

**Is jQuery.isFunction() superior?**

According to *[Kyle Florence](http://kflorence.myopenid.com/)* `jQuery.isFunction()` it could superior in some situations. Particularly useful in some edge cases when using jQuery methods, see his [explanation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/#comment-128339529).

> In certain situations in some
>   browsers, things are incorrectly
>   returned as the "function" type, or
>   things that are in fact functions are
>   returned as another type. There are
>   several test cases you can see here:
>   https://github.com/jquery/jque...
>
> One example:
>
> var obj =
>   document.createElement("object");
>
> // Firefox says this is a function
>   typeof obj; // => "function"
>
> Keep in mind these are mostly edge
>   cases, but the reason $.isFunction was
>   made was simply to be positive about
>   something being a function (which can
>   be quite important for the jQuery
>   library itself, maybe not so much for
>   your code).

Thanks **[patrick dw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113716/patrick-dw)** for pointing out Kyles Article. (Patrick DW deleted his account)

From [jQuery.com](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isfunction/#entry-longdesc)

> Note: As of jQuery 1.3, functions provided by the browser like alert()
>   and DOM element methods like getAttribute() are not guaranteed to be
>   detected as functions in browsers such as Internet Explorer.

Comment: Since it's tagged with `jQuery`, I'll give this a +1 because jQuery uses a slightly safer means of testing for a function.

Comment: maybe a combination of jquery.isFunction and check if 'undefined' is in place. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20027726/1257607)

Answer (score 17):

Like so:

```
if (typeof myFunc != 'undefined') {
    // Assign myFunc
}
```

**Don't** just test it against `undefined`, which is not a constant and can be reassigned.

Comment: This is great for ensuring `myFunc` is defined but it does not verify that `myFunc` is in fact a function.

Answer (score 7):

```
if (typeof(functionName) == 'function') {
}
```

.

Comment: He just wants to know if it is defined, not whether or not it's a function.

Comment: Right, but perhaps he doesn't want to overwrite it even if it is just a non-function value.

Comment: @alpha123: The question clearly asks how to check if a **function** is defined.

Comment: @alpha123 You're right but it doesn't matter if it's solved his problem. The answer is valid!

Answer (score 3):

typeof return string,so you can use the JavaScript typeof operator to find the type of a JavaScript variable.

```
if ( typeof(youerFunctionName) === 'undefined' )
{
    console.log('undefined');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (myFunc !== undefined) {
  // myFunc is defined
  foo();
}
```

or

```
if (myFunc === undefined) {
  // myFunc is not defined
  qux();
}
```

Comment: `undefined` isn't a constant. Testing against it is dangerous.

Comment: Okay then. Every time before using it: `undefined = void(0);` but you shouldn't need this because setting the value of `undefined` is just stupid.

Comment: Stay away from the `void` operator, it's confusing. You gotta read Douglas Crockford man.

Comment: I do have to give you a little credit for actually finding a use for it though. :P

Comment: Code that redefines `undefined` *should* break.

Comment: @patrik dw: no, it must break

Comment: Absolutely. I get a little tired of the Crockford zombies.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([function] != undefined) {
  [do stuff]
}
```

You can also use [jQuery's isFunction()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/) to check it.

Answer (score 1):

Say your function is called `func`:

```
if (func) {
  // Function is already defined (or at least something is defined there)
} else {
  // Function is not defined
}
```

Comment: `var func = false;` beat that

Comment: `false` isn't a function, so the test is still valid. Of course, if you really wanted to break it then you could do `var func = true`.  But I'm assuming that if it's not a function it won't be anything, which is probably a safe assumption in most cases where you'd want to check for this kind of thing.

Comment: Yeah, but the test would show that it isn't defined, when in fact it is. Perhaps he doesn't want to overwrite it even if it's just a non-function value.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
/*********************************/

if(typeof(callback) == 'function')

/*********************************/
```

here is a working [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cxnqw82s/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(){}

if(typeof test  != "undefined")
    // function is allready defined
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to check if a function is already defined:

```
if ( typeof(myFunc()) === 'undefined' )
{
    console.log('myFunc undefined');
}
else 
{
    console.log('myFunc defined');
}
```