# jQuery isFunction check error "function is not defined"

Tags: jquery, function

I want to do a check whether a function exist or not before trying to run it. Here is my code:

```
if ($.isFunction(myfunc())) {
    console.log("function exist, run it!!!");
}
```

However, when the function is not available I got the error:

> myfunc is not defined

How can I do the detection? Here is my working test: http://jsfiddle.net/3m3Y3/

Answer (score 138, accepted):

By putting `()` after the function name, you're actually trying to run it right there in your first line.

Instead, you should just use the function name without running it:

```
if ($.isFunction(myfunc)) {
```

**However** - If `myfunc` is not a function and is not any other defined variable, this will still return an error, although a different one. Something like `myfunc is not defined`.

You should check that the name exists, and then check that it's a function, like this:

```
if (typeof myfunc !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction(myfunc)) {
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/sXV6w/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work. I have tested it here: http://jsfiddle.net/3m3Y3/

Comment: @user1995781 you need to quote the word `'undefined'`

Comment: this doesn't work for jQuery dependency plugins, `if (!!$.prototype.functionName)` worked for me, check the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108832/jquery-test-for-whether-an-object-has-a-method)

Comment: Can also use ```if (typeof myfunc === 'function')```

Answer (score 13):

try this

```
if(typeof myfunc == 'function'){
    alert("exist");
}else{
    alert("not exist");
}
```