# Check if function is defined on `jQuery` object

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-plugins

We can check if function is defined using

```
$.isFunction(myFunc) {
    myFunc();
}
```

But, I want to check if a function is defined on `jQuery`/`$` object. Is there any way to check this.

pseudo-code of what I'm looking for:

```
if ($.hasFun(myFunc)) {
    $('selector').myFunc();
}
```

Also, if I've jQuery plugins on my page, how can I check if the function exists on the plugin?

Comment: You have a nice answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5159690/1257607)

Comment: @DanielV The answer is nice, but question is different, read the question again. `Check if function is defined on `jQuery` object`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check the prototype object of jQuery which is referred by `jQuery.fn`, so

```
if ($.isFunction($.fn.myFunc)) {
    $('selector').myFunc();
}
```

Comment: @Tushar it depends on how the plugin is designed.... if it is widget style then it won't work....

Comment: And how can we check for widgets?

Comment: @Tushar As far as I can see, widgets doesn't expose the available method